# Is it possible to add classname to render array of node title using entity meta wrapper?

Tags: 7, theming

I would like to know how to add a class name to node title by altering the render array. I examined the wrapper object

```
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $nid)
```

by using

```
dpm($wrapper->getPropertyInfo())
```

and

```
debug($wrapper)
```

but got not the smallest idea how to change the markup of the title, i.e. adding a class name.

Comment: I dont think it is. Have you checked this related thread. Though the approach is via template.php if on Drupal 7. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/77398/how-to-attach-css-classes-to-the-h1-title-attributes-if-node-is-page-dynamic

Comment: Are you using [title](https://www.drupal.org/project/title) module?

Comment: Yes, i am using title module.